# Is it possible to select both, IS NOT NULL and IS NULL simultaneously?

Tags: mysql, null, isnull

I want to have this query in order to pull out everything, that is literally both, `null` and not `null` values.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `column` IS NULL AND NOT NULL
```

I actually expect the same result as if not provide any `WHERE` at all:

```
# should produce the same result set
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `column` IS NULL AND NOT NULL 
SELECT * FROM `tbl`
```

Although the clause `IS NULL AND NOT NULL` is syntactically correct, it doesn't return correct result, it doesn't return anything at all. Is it possible with MySQL?

`IS NULL AND NOT NULL` - correct syntax, but wrong result - returns just nothing

`IS NULL OR NOT NULL` - same as above

`IS NULL AND IS NOT NULL` - error, syntax incorrect

UPD:

Order of `NOT` makes sense when used with `GROUP BY`.

`col IS NOT NULL OR col IS NULL` - ok

`col IS NULL OR col IS NOT NULL` - `GROUP BY` doesn't work correctly

Comment: In my understanding `IS NULL AND NOT NULL` should't return any results as it is a condition that is contradicting. No result can fulfil this.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Provide sample data along with your desired results

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WHERE `column` IS NULL OR `column` IS NOT NULL
```

But such condition makes no sense as it is the same as no condition.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine this condition from the inside out. `not` is a boolean operator that negates a boolean passed to it. Negating a `null` returns a `null`. Now you have an `and` operator applied between a boolean condition (`column is null`) which may be `true` or `false` and a `null`, which will result in `null.` As `null` is not `true`, no rows will ever be returned for this query.

In short, there are two things wrong with your condition

- The second term is missing the column
- A column cannot be both `null` and not `null` simultaneously. Your logic calls for the `or` operator.

To sum it all up:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `column` IS NULL OR `column` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: It works. But I found that order is important here. When `NOT` is in the second part, as in your example, it breaks `GROUP BY`. However `col IS NOT NULL OR col IS NULL` works all right. I better change logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl` WHERE col1 in
(SELECT col1
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT col1
FROM `tbl`
WHERE `column` IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT col1
FROM `tbl`
WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL) A
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

This will give you the required result.
Here, col1 is the column for which we have duplicate data in table. Feel free to ask any question.